# Functions vs. Objects in JavaScript and the instantiation without function

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, ecma

I know, that a function in JavaScript is nothing else than an object that has a prototype property with a constructor what can be used to instantiate new objects.

However, it is not possible to do the following:

```
 let Pear = {
    prototype : Object.prototype
 };
 let p = new Pear();  //Throws "caught TypeError: Pear is not a constructor"
```

In my opinion, this should be exactly the same like:

```
 function Pear() {

 }
 let p = new Pear();
```

what works. 
I am just wondering where the difference is. Is there a fix for my first way?
Or are "functions" no "real" objects and get treated differently? It's really just a curiosity thing. Nothing important actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object that `new` operates on must implement the `[[Construct]]` internal method, otherwise it will throw a TypeError exception (what you observed).

Knowing that, I don't believe you could use `new` in conjunction with an object produced with the object literal syntax.

However, if you're defining things like that, you probably don't *want* to. You could create a new Object including the properties of a former with `Object.assign()`.

```
let p = Object.assign({}, Pear);
```

Alternatively, you could use another way to change the prototype of the object to something else.

Comment: Thats what I also figured out: There are two different kinds of objects in JavaScript. Function-Objects and Object-Objects. Function Objects have a special property (string) that contains the evaluable content you can call with (). Normal objects do not contain this property. It does not seem to be possible to convert an Object-Object into a Function-Object.